# Copy only new or modified files/directories in C#

Tags: c#, copy, filesystems

I am trying to create a simple “directory/file copy" console application in C#. What I need is to copy all folders and files (keeping the original hierarchy) from one drive to another, like from drive C:\Data to drive E:\Data.

However, I only want it to copy any NEW or MODIFIED files from the source to the destination. 
If the file on the destination drive is newer than the one on the source drive, then it does not copy.

(the problem)

In the code I have, it's comparing file "abc.pdf" in the source with file "xyz.pdf" in the destination and thus is overwriting the destination file with whatever is in the source even though the destination file is newer. I am trying to figure out how to make it compare "abc.pdf" in the source to "abc.pdf" in the destination.

This works if I drill the source and destination down to a specific file, but when I back out to the folder level, it overwrites the destination file with the source file, even though the destination file is newer.

(my solutions – that didn’t work)

I thought by putting the “if (file.LastWriteTime > destination.LastWriteTime)” after the “foreach” command, that it would compare the files in the two folders, File1 source to File1 destination, but it’s not.

It seems I’m missing something in either the “FileInfo[]”, “foreach” or “if” statements to make this a one-to-one comparison. I think maybe some reference to the “Path.Combine” statement or a “SearchOption.AllDirectories”, but I’m not sure.

Any suggestions?

As you can see from my basic code sample, I'm new to C# so please put your answer in simple terms.

Thank you.

Here is the code I have tried, but it’s not working.

```
class Copy  
{  
    public static void CopyDirectory(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo destination)  
    {  
        if (!destination.Exists)  
        {  
            destination.Create();  
        }  
        // Copy files.  
        FileInfo[] files = source.GetFiles();  
        FileInfo[] destFiles = destination.GetFiles();  
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)  
            foreach (FileInfo fileD in destFiles)  
                // Copy only modified files    
                    if (file.LastWriteTime > fileD.LastWriteTime)  
                    {  
                        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination.FullName,  
                        file.Name), true);  
                    }  

                // Copy all new files  
                else  
                if (!fileD.Exists)  
                {  
                    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination.FullName, file.Name), true);  
                }  
        // Process subdirectories.  
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = source.GetDirectories();  
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)  
        {  
            // Get destination directory.  
            string destinationDir = Path.Combine(destination.FullName, dir.Name);  
            // Call CopyDirectory() recursively.  
            CopyDirectory(dir, new DirectoryInfo(destinationDir));  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good start, but you say its not working?  Whats not working?

Comment: "it's not working" isn't really a good problem description. Please edit your question and elaborate which behaviour you expected and what happened instead. Did you try to **debug** your code? I'm pretty sure the first problem is that `source.GetFiles()` and `destination.GetFiles()` don't necessarily give you the files in the same order. So you're probably comparing the dates of `abc.pdf` with `xyz.pdf`.

Comment: I know this doesn't address your question, but why aren't you using some readily available system tool for such a task (such as robocopy on Windows, for example)?

Comment: Rene' Vogt, you're correct, it's comparing "abc.pdf" with "xyz.pdf" and thus is overwriting the destination file with what ever is in the source even though the destination file is newer. I am trying to figure out how to make it compare "abc.pdf" in the source to "abc.pdf" in the destination. I can do this if I drill the source and destination down to a specific file, but I want this to compare multiple folders and files. And that's where I am having problems. I just don't know enough about C# yet to figure how to do this. The books I have don't go this in depth.

Comment: To "elgonzo", I'm using this method because, when I get it working I want to add more script to create a log of what files/folders were copied for the day and have the program send an email out with the log attached. I don't know if robocopy will do that. As I mentioned, I am new to this and learning as much as I can. Video tutorials and books can only take you so far and you can't ask them questions.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question to try and satisfy the minimum requirements for posting a question here. Let me know if I need to do more modifications or to simply delete this question and post it again with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the array of files in "source" and check for a matching name in "destination"

```
/// <summary>
    /// checks whether the target file needs an update (if it doesn't exist: it needs one)
    /// </summary>
    public static bool NeedsUpdate(FileInfo localFile, DirectoryInfo localDir, DirectoryInfo backUpDir)
    {
        bool needsUpdate = false;

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(backUpDir.FullName, localFile.Name)))
        {
            needsUpdate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            FileInfo backUpFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(backUpDir.FullName, localFile.Name));

            DateTime lastBackUp = backUpFile.LastWriteTimeUtc;
            DateTime lastChange = localFile.LastWriteTimeUtc;

            if (lastChange != lastBackUp)
            {
                needsUpdate = true;
            }
            else
            {/*no change*/}
        }
        return needsUpdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I modified my code with the suggestions above and all went well. It did exactly as I expected.

However, the problem I ran into was the amount of time it took run the application on a large folder. (containing 6,000 files and 5 sub-folders)

On a small folder, (28 files in 5 sub-folders) it only took a few seconds to run. But, on the larger folder it took 35 minutes to process only 1,300 files.

Solution:

The code below will do the same thing but much faster. This new version processed 6,000 files in about 10 seconds. It processed 40,000 files in about 1 minute and 50 seconds.

What this new code does (and doesn’t do)

If the destination folder is empty, copy all from the source to the destination.

If the destination has some or all of the same files / folders as the source, compare and copy any new or modified files from the source to the destination.

If the destination file is newer than the source, don’t copy.

So, here’s the code to make it happen. Enjoy and share.

Thanks to everyone who helped me get a better understanding of this.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;


    namespace VSU1vFileCopy
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const string Src_FOLDER = @"C:\Data";
                const string Dest_FOLDER = @"E:\Data";
                string[] originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Src_FOLDER, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                Array.ForEach(originalFiles, (originalFileLocation) =>
                {
                    FileInfo originalFile = new FileInfo(originalFileLocation);
                    FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(originalFileLocation.Replace(Src_FOLDER, Dest_FOLDER));

                    if (destFile.Exists)
                    {
                        if (originalFile.Length > destFile.Length)
                        {
                            originalFile.CopyTo(destFile.FullName, true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFile.DirectoryName);
                        originalFile.CopyTo(destFile.FullName, false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```